# Better quality photo from passport-facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, passport.js, passport-facebook

How does one get a better quality picture from `passport-facebook`, the picture that I recieve in `photos[0].value` is 50x50 which is pretty poor, I wish to get atleast 150x150.I was trying to mess with link - no luck. Is it possible to retrieve better quality profile picture?

Edit: My current fb strategy setup:

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: 'xxxxxx',
    clientSecret: 'xxxxx',
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:4242/facebook/cb',
    profileFields: ['id', 'name', 'displayName', 'photos', 'hometown', 'profileUrl'],
    passReqToCallback: true
}, ...
```

Comment: You should show at least some code...

Comment: Honestly i thought that question is pretty clear without code, i could be wrong, added.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to specify the `profileFields` property as described in

- https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook#profile-fields

like the following to retrieve a larger picture:

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    // clientID, clientSecret and callbackURL
    profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'picture.type(large)', ...]
  },
  // verify callback
  ...
));
```

or you could change the `strategy.js` file of the `passport-facebook` module at line 221 to

```
'photos':      'picture.type(large)'
```

See

- https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/blob/master/lib/strategy.js#L221

Comment: It looks legit, but maybe i'm doing something wrong but i can't find a list of possible profilefields anywhere, ah got it, there is a list in the source, that you are linked.

Comment: Yes. but as i said im recieving low res picture, `picture.type(large)` worked, but i got no idea why. Where I can even see docs and info about the fact that i can specify `picture.type(large)`  in profilefileds, and what else i can specify there?

Comment: Because this is a Graph API functionality. Have a look at the Facebook docs.

Comment: Ok, i will, (Yet, it feels like the link to it or some kind of mention can be supplied in passprot-facebook docs, that could be pretty useful) 
So, thank You for Your help =)